# How to insert (append) a string containing XML as XML into inner XML (or remove a parent tag but keep the content) with lxml in Python?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm trying to insert text into XML with lxml. The text contains XML which is supposed to become part of the XML it gets inserted into.

The following code does not work:

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.fromstring('<tag><src></src><src></src></tag>')

new_mix = 'This <x id="1"/> rocks the <x id="2"/>!'

for src in tree.findall('.//src'):
    src.append(etree.fromstring(new_mix))
    
print(etree.tostring(tree))
```

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

If I add a `<p></p>` parent tag to `new_mix`, so it becomes `'<p>This <x id="1"/> rocks the <x id="2"/>!</p>'`, it works:

```xml
b'<tag><src><p>This <x id="1"/> rocks the <x id="2"/>!</p></src><src><p>This <x id="1"/> rocks the <x id="2"/>!</p></src></tag>'
```

But how do I avoid or remove the `<p>` or any other parent tags while keeping the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the wrapper idea and using its descendants including `text()`nodes

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.fromstring('<tag><src></src><src></src></tag>')

for esrc in tree.xpath('/tag/src'):
    u = etree.fromstring('<fake>This <x id="1"/> rocks the <x id="2"/>!</fake>')
    toadd = u.xpath('/fake/*')
    toaddtext = u.xpath('/fake/text()')
    esrc.text = toaddtext[0]
    for ele in toadd:
        esrc.append(ele)

print(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True).decode('utf-8'))
```

result

```
<tag>
  <src>This <x id="1"/> rocks the <x id="2"/>!</src>
  <src>This <x id="1"/> rocks the <x id="2"/>!</src>
</tag>
```

This xpath `/fake/*` finds 2 elements that contains `tail` text

```
<x id="1"/> rocks the  
<x id="2"/>!
```

so `/fake/text()` is needed to find `This`

Answer (score 1):

There are other Python packages that offer more functionality, for instance [saxonche](https://pypi.org/project/saxonche/) offers complete XSLT 3.0 with XPath 3.1 (which has a function `parse-xml-fragment`):

```
from saxonche import PySaxonProcessor

with PySaxonProcessor(license=False) as saxon:

    xdm_doc = saxon.parse_xml(xml_text='<tag><src></src><src></src></tag>')

    new_mix = 'This <x id="1"/> rocks the <x id="2"/>!'

    xslt = '''<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
      <xsl:param name="mix" as="xs:string" required="yes"/>
      <xsl:variable name="parsed_mix" select="parse-xml-fragment($mix)"/>
      <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
      <xsl:template match="src">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$parsed_mix"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>'''

    xslt30_processor = saxon.new_xslt30_processor()

    xslt30_executable = xslt30_processor.compile_stylesheet(stylesheet_text=xslt)

    xslt30_executable.set_parameter('mix', saxon.make_string_value(new_mix))

    xslt_result = xslt30_executable.apply_templates_returning_value(xdm_value=xdm_doc)

    print(xslt_result)
```

Output:

```
<tag>
   <src>This <x id="1"/> rocks the <x id="2"/>!</src>
   <src>This <x id="1"/> rocks the <x id="2"/>!</src>
</tag>
```

Complete Python API reference is at https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc12/html/saxonc.html. Some samples are at https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation12/index.html#!samples/samples_python.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of fake it...

First, change `new_mix` to

```
new_mix = '<src>This <x id="1"/> rocks the <x id="2"/>!</src>'
```

and then change you `for loop` to

```
for src in tree.findall('.//src'):
  t = src.getparent()
  t.remove(src)
  t.append(etree.fromstring(new_mix))
```

That should get you there, at least based on the sample xml.

Comment: True, true. My example unfortunately doesn't show or mention it but in the real world problem, `src` may contain unknown attributes that I need to preserved. I'd have to figure out how to ensure those stay as they are first.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this text string as CDATA:

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import CDATA

tree = etree.fromstring('<tag><src></src><src></src></tag>')

new_mix = 'This <x id="1"/> rocks the <x id="2"/>!'

for src in tree.findall('.//src'):
    src.text = CDATA(new_mix)
    
etree.dump(tree)

et = etree.ElementTree(tree)
et.write('output.xml', xml_declaration=True, pretty_print=True)
```

Output file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<tag>
  <src><![CDATA[This <x id="1"/> rocks the <x id="2"/>!]]></src>
  <src><![CDATA[This <x id="1"/> rocks the <x id="2"/>!]]></src>
</tag>
```

The lxml can also parse CDATA easily:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=True)
with open('output.xml', "rb") as source:
    tree1 = etree.parse(source, parser=parser)
    
for elem in tree1.iter():
    print(elem.tag, elem.text)
```

Output:

```
src This <x id="1"/> rocks the <x id="2"/>!
src This <x id="1"/> rocks the <x id="2"/>!
```

Comment: I love how simple this is but the inserted XML needs to be parse-able and there seems not to be a simple way to remove the CDATA encapsulation.

Comment: @qubodup I added the lines for parsing CDATA too. Hope it will help.

Comment: The XML will be fed to a software that I can't change. Specifically this is for inserting text and tags into a .xliff file to be read by a CAT tool. This tool interprets content inside CDATA as plain text, as if I had written the string as text into src, but I need it to read the <x> tags for its internal tag system. That's what I meant by parse-able.